# Print array value and variable in order

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am sure there is a simpler solution to this that I am over looking

Here is some code that basically describes what I am doing:

```
$array = array('1.4','2.7','4.1','5.9'); 
$score = '4.4';
foreach($array as $value) {
    if($score>$value){
        $x = $value;
    }
}
foreach($array as $value) {
    if($x==$value){
        echo $value."<br>";
        echo $score."<-- <br>";
    } else {
        echo $value."<br>";
    }
}
```

Will display as:

```
1.4
2.7
4.1
4.4<--
5.9
```

What I am trying to do is print the array values with the score value in order.

Comment: what type of order? increasing order or decreasing order?

Comment: I'm confused.  What's the problem here?  Is that result not what you want?  It's printing the values in order with `$score` where it belongs.  What result *do* you want?

Comment: yeah man i am also confused.

Comment: sorry, i should have been more clear. the result i am looking for is in the original question, however, i should have stated that my array is actually a multiple dimensional json file (i will repost a new question with full code examples later). i was really just looking for a better way to execute the code above as Mike Brant stated below it is a 'rudimentary attempt'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you change the array to actual numerical values and then sort it?

```
$array = array(1.4, 2.7, 4.1, 5.9);
$score = 4.4;

$array[] = $score;
sort($array);
```

Or if you need to work with strings:

```
$array = array('1.4', '2.7', '4.1', '5.9');
$score = '4.4';
$array[] = $score;
sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Comment: hey man you are much experienced programmer but i want to ask you what he wanted to do @Mike Brant? I can't understand what he wanted to do?

Comment: @AspiringAqib I assume here wanted to do what the title of his post said "Print array value and variable in order" (i.e. order the one value within the existing array).  His code is some rudimentary attempt at inserting the value into the array at the right spot, but only works because the array he starts with is ordered.  I have proposed a more general solution.

Comment: thanks buddy! you have good knowledge about these stuff! hats off :)

Answer (score 0):

For sorting, what might be the easiest is to use the `sort()` method ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)).

You're overwriting `$x` each time through your first loop. ... the way it's written, when you're done with the first loop, `$x` has the last value that's less than `$score`. (Are you identifying a cut-off line?)

After you've sorted with the `sort()` method, your second loop should work as you intend. There are tighter ways to do the printing (for example, you can `implode()`), but what you've got should work.